# Layer not rendering correctly

Tags: rendering, layers

I've been following BlenderGuru's tutorials on making a donut and cup.

I've gotten right to the end and now when I click 'Render Image', I don't get the icing:

[image]

The particles (sprinkles) are displaying, but not the pink icing.  I cannot figure out why.

The blender file is here:
https://www.pastefile.com/xVhP4G

And a screenshot of Blender:
[image]

Can anyone help me figure out why?

Comment: Check that the camera icon for the missing object is enable in the outliner

Answer (score 3):

I guess you need to select your icing, then go in the *Properties* panel > *Particles* > *Render* and  enable the *Show Emitter* option.

[image]

Comment: Ahhh I bet you that's the problem! I'll check later, thanks!