# Missing elements while rendering an image in Blender

Tags: rendering

I am totally new to Blender and I came upon an issue I can't solve by myself. I tried some solutions for a similar problem but seems not to work in my case. I was following a blender tutorial and everything was good until the last step when I wanted to render my last view. In my object mode, I have all elements but while rendering an image some of them are missing. Do you have any idea what is happening here because I am lost? I am using Blender Version 2.81 on Macbook Pro.

Here is a view from my Object Mode

[image: Here is a view from Object Mode]

and here is rendered result ...

[image: and here is render result ...]

Would really appreciate advise how to fix this problem ;))

Comment: Hello and welcome :). You need to check Show Emitter in *Particles > Render > Show Emitter*. https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/136018/78972

Comment: Wow, thank you soo much! It works now ;) I tried to solve the problem since this morning ha Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

Check and see if you have this option checked in your missing object.

[image: Show in render]